# Connect my mac to my external local asp server

Tags: windows-server-2003, mac, asp

In our office we have several PC's that network to a Windows 2003 Server so we can run local sites for testing etc and so we all have access to rather than have them on individual PC's.

We have a iMac that we use for mac development as well as sites we work on.

Since we have dreamweaver on this iMac we would like to connect as the PC's.  We can obviously see the sites etc in dreamweaver but the issue is when we run/test them within a browser they do not respond / display.  Is says it cannot find the server.

Everything is set up correctly but its not see the server - serverName. The link below is what is run with in a browser.

http://serverName/asite/default.asp

MY question is what settings would I need to do to get the Mac to respond and display the websites locally on the local server.

Comment: I think that you really need to re-read what you posted and edit it. It's borderline unintelligible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply went onto  the server and found out its IP address (goto run, type in CMD then in command prompt type ipconfig) then using this i managed to connect to my external windows server through my mac so I can view my amends locally